# How would I fix a middle div at 600px width, while having a left and right sidebar expand when the screen grows in width?

Tags: html, css

I've made a few attempts at getting this right, mostly experimenting with the `width` property. No success.

My goal is to recreate Twitter's desktop view. The way Twitter works is, there's a central div with an infinite scroll. On the left and right are two sidebars, fully expanded beyond 1285px. I've got that handled.

What I don't have is a way to emulate this behavior: When the screen expands beyond 128px, the sidebars and main feed stay the same width, while empty space appears to the left and right of the sidebars.

The content of the sidebars will stay at a fixed width, by the way. Just the div containing the content will grow! So I'll put stuff in the "container" divs and fix the size of the container while the outer divs expand.

I'm showing you guys a simplified version of my html/css which I believe will do the job. It would cover several pages if I copied in the real sidebars.

```css
#sidebar {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

#right_sidebar{
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

#search {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 3px solid cadetblue;
}

#search_main {
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="sidebar_container"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="right_sidebar">
      <div id="right_sidebar_container"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="search" class="centered">
      <div id="main_feed_container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As it is in my browser, all three sections expand and contract as the browser is resized. I want the middle div to stay fixed in width while the sidebars expand.

The specifics of what I've tried are this:

1. I set the `min-width` property of the left and right sidebar to 30% and the `width` property of the `.centered` class to `600px`. This one's botched. It causes the middle div to be a wee little 200px wide thing.
2. While the center div has `width: 600px;` and the sidebars have `width: 30%;`, I set the `.centered` position to `relative` and the left sidebar to `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`. The center div ended up sitting on top of the left sidebar. Nope.
3. I put a `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` on the `body` div. Ended up with my divs out of order. So I changed the order. Doesn't work either. Making the screen thinner still "squishes" the content in the middle div.

Here's a code sandbox to mess around with: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-moon-lhz6z If you can make the div with a "c" in it stay between the "a" and "b" divs, allowing for those outer divs to expand while the "c" div is fixed at 600px width, you're my hero!

Leave a comment if I am unclear with what I am trying to accomplish. I can make something in Paint to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}

article {
  width: 600px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside>left</aside>
  <article>600px</article>
  <aside>right</aside>
</section>
```